# Insert line in iptables's file

Tags: bash

I work with bash file and I want to insert and get  line in iptables's file

```
# Firewall configuration written by system-config-firewall
# Manual customization of this file is not recommended.
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
{My Line Here}
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 5353 -d 224.0.0.251 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

replace {My line here} to

```
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

1. Then  I want to find and get firewall open ports an display them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed 's/-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT/-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT\n-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT/g' <filename> > temp ; mv temp <filename>
```

Replace the `<filename>` by the actual file. This works only if the preceding line is `-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT`

Comment: `netstat -tulpn | less`. I think this would help. More information here http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-rhel-linux-open-port-using-iptables/